# Error: "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" while playing mp4 file using NetStream object (Actionscript/Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, video, mp4, netstream

I am using NetStream, NetConnection and Video object to play an mp4 file which is hosted over a web server using http.

The mp4 file URL is for example: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/file.mp4

This is an AIR application and the relevant code is pasted below:

---

```
var url:String = <some http url>;

connect_nc = new NetConnection();
connect_nc.connect(null);

stream_ns = new NetStream(connect_nc);

var ns_object:Object = new Object();
ns_object.onPlayStatus = ns_onPlayStatus;

stream_ns.client = ns_object;
videoMP4.attachNetStream(stream_ns);           

stream_ns.bufferTime = 1.0 // 1 sec       
stream_ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatusEventHandler);
stream_ns.play(url);
```

---

This code works when run on MAC OS X. But it does not work when run on Windows XP. I get the error:

```
NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
```

I also tried playing the URL using VLC player on the same windows XP host. The URL is valid because VLC can play it.

In my particular case, the http URL is hosted by WMP 12 (window media player 12) on Win 7 machine where I am using the media sharing feature of WMP 12.

After further looking into http traffic on wireshark, here is what i found.

After running wireshark on the host running the adobe AIR application, it seems that it is getting a HTTP 406 response from

the server being run by WMP 12.

```
GET /WMPNSSv4/63903908/1_ezVGREUzQTA4LTdDQzQtNDJFMy1CNDVDLUZEMjA4MDE5OUM4Q30uMC44.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.102:10243
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en) AppleWebKit/526.9+ (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/1.5
Referer: app:/clicker.swf
x-flash-version: 10,0,12,36
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: text/xml, application/xml, application/xhtml+xml, text/html;q=0.9, text/plain;q=0.8, text/css, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif;q=0.8, application/x-shockwave-flash, video/mp4;q=0.9, flv-application/octet-stream;q=0.8, video/x-flv;q=0.7, audio/mp4, application/futuresplash, */*;q=0.5
```

---

### Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Oct 2009 23:21:14 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
TransferMode.DLNA.ORG: Streaming
Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2010 22:52:48 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

On MAC:

It receives 200 OK response though, and that is why the video streaming works.

```
GET /WMPNSSv4/63903908/1_ezVGREUzQTA4LTdDQzQtNDJFMy1CNDVDLUZEMjA4MDE5OUM4Q30uMC44.m p4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.102:10243
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/526.9+ (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/1.5.3
Referer: app:/clicker.swf
X-Flash-Version: 10,0,42,34
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

---

### Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1524867
Content-Type: video/mp4
Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Oct 2009 23:21:14 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
TransferMode.DLNA.ORG: Streaming
Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2010 22:56:20 GMT
```

The difference that I can see in the HTTP requests between the Windows XP and MAC version is the Accept: Header. Is the Accept: header value wrong for Windows case because of which WMP 12 rejects
the http request.

If i run the adobe AIR application on Win 7 host, i see the same failure.

Am I using the NetStream object incorrectly or it is a bug in WMP 12 code not being able to parse
the header properly or it is a flex bug where it is generating an incorrect accept: header?

Answer (score 0):

I believe WMP 12 incorrectly handles 'Accept' header in a request. If it contains 'q' (quality) parameter, then WMP ignores this mime-type. And if there are no other suitable mime-types for WMP, it will respond with 406 Not Acceptable error.

I encountered this issues when was trying to display DLNA image in Chrome browser.

I used [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) utility to send requests with different headers to figure out what goes wrong.

Request that results in 406 Not Acceptable error:

```
curl -v -o file.jpg -H "Accept: text/html,*/*,q=0.8" "http://127.0.0.1:10243/WMPNSSv4/3065481158/0_e0I5MzA1MTRELUYwMEEtNEQwRC1CQzg4LTg3NEI5QjQ4MDYyM30uMC5C.jpg"

GET /WMPNSSv4/3065481158/0_e0I5MzA1MTRELUYwMEEtNEQwRC1CQzg4LTg3NEI5QjQ4MDYyM30uMC5C.jpg HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.31.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:10243
Accept: text/html,*/*;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 May 2013 21:01:09 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
TransferMode.DLNA.ORG: Interactive
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2013 09:10:32 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

Successful request:

```
curl -v -o file.jpg -H "Accept: text/html,*/*" "http://127.0.0.1:10243/WMPNSSv4/3065481158/0_e0I5MzA1MTRELUYwMEEtNEQwRC1CQzg4LTg3NEI5QjQ4MDYyM30uMC5C.jpg"

GET /WMPNSSv4/3065481158/0_e0I5MzA1MTRELUYwMEEtNEQwRC1CQzg4LTg3NEI5QjQ4MDYyM30uMC5C.jpg HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.31.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:10243
Accept: text/html,*/*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2394679
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 May 2013 21:01:09 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
TransferMode.DLNA.ORG: Interactive
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2013 09:10:40 GMT
```